# How to reset PlayerPrefs on game start, but keep value when loading scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script which has an int variable. In that script I set PlayerPrefs from that int, and then I call that PlayerPref in another script on another scene.

When i play new game, i want to prefs to reset, and keep track further in game, even when loading between scene.

Problem is when I start game, value is 0, then i go to another scene and make score 3, return to main scene and value is 0 again, when it needs to be 3.

I want to make "New Game" functionality, but normal data saving if user goes from scene to scene.

```
void Start()
    {       
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();        
    }
```

```
void Update()
    {
        passScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("pass");
        passScore2 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("pass2");
        passScore3 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("pass3");
    }
```

Original Int is static int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void Start()` runs every time you change scenes and the script is active.

You will have to delete all player preferences only when the game actually starts.

I would make this:
Create a new empty object, attach a script to it.

In the script, type this:

```
private void Awake()
{
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
}
```

Don't forget to attach the script to an empty game object and delete what you have previously done (delete the void Start where you delete player prefs).

EDIT: I forgot to say what this does! Sorry! The `DontDestoryOnLoad` makes an object stick in the hierarchy even if you switch scenes. The `Awake` bit automatically runs when a script awakes (i.e. when it's first seen). In combination, these two make the `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll()` function only run once, which is at game start. Doesn't matter if you switch scenes.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I new I need to use both but not in what way and in what function. Thank you.